# How to get union type from object value in some key instead `string[]`

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have `IHeaderColumns` interface and  for Table's Header.

```
interface IHeaderColumns {
  id?: string
  text: string
  value: string
  align?: 'left' | 'center' | 'right'
  sortable?: boolean
  class?: string[] | string
  width?: string
  filter?: {
    type: 'uuid' | 'string' | 'name' | 'datetime' | 'option'
  }
}

const headerInstaceColumns: IHeaderColumns[] = [
  {
    id: 'instances_list_table_instances_column_id',
    text: 'ID',
    value: 'id',
    sortable: false
  },
  {
    id: 'instances_list_table_instances_column_name',
    text: 'Name',
    value: 'name',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    id: 'instances_list_table_instances_column_status',
    text: 'Status',
    value: 'status',
    sortable: true
  }
]
```

I need to shape object type for the Table's value as dynamic type like this:

```
type TableRow = {
  [P in (IHeaderColumns['value'] as const)]: any
}

const items: TableRow[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Instance-1',
    status: 'ACTIVE'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Instance-2',
    status: 'SHUTOFF'
  }
]
```

**Possible to do?**

### -- UPDATE --

I already tried but type `T` is inferred to `IHeaderColumns`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will need a generic function to create the `headerInstanceColumns` array.

The information you are looking for is not in the `IColumnHeaders` type because it does not know about any objects which use the type. The information is also not (yet) in the `headerInstaceColumns` array because it just uses the `IColumnHeaders` type explicitly. So we either initialize the array with `as const` or use a generic function to create it.

```
function createHeaderInstanceColumns<
  T extends (IColumnHeaders & { value: S })[], 
  S extends string
>(columns: T): T {
  return columns
}
```

This function constrains the passed array to be of type `IColumnHeaders`. It also uses the generic type `S` to infer the `value` types.

Now we can create the `headerInstanceColumns` array.

```
const headerInstanceColumns = createHeaderInstanceColumns([
  {
    id: 'instances_list_table_instances_column_id',
    text: 'ID',
    value: 'id',
    sortable: false
  },
  {
    id: 'instances_list_table_instances_column_name',
    text: 'Name',
    value: 'name',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    id: 'instances_list_table_instances_column_status',
    text: 'Status',
    value: 'status',
    sortable: true
  }
])
```

And use its type in the `TableRow` type.

```
type TableRow = {
  [P in typeof headerInstanceColumns[number]['value']]: any
}

const items: TableRow[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Instance-1',
    status: 'ACTIVE'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Instance-2',
    status: 'SHUTOFF'
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2AbArgWxAAkI4ATaAZ2QG8AoZZYMgfgC5lKwpQBzB5JAAeYDlx4h%20jAG5w8EMdz4C5wXiHbIA5NggwwW5AB9tScNEMmtPXgAsDAypihg4AI12a3mHKRACEbDhKSk1xPgBtAF1jTiVJAQB3ZjBbMPipZBhgbEgoTXpGRjAATwAHBW1cXGZLbXDJOq0QOHwIJrI4SDBgNqbMMp7MEC0BAF86CboEYa5kW1IKKFQQLjgQJCw8QmoAXmQEKFJIEnJoFbWNiC2CVYAKCIFCouYOLVBLpEoAfWxgLm%20rg8EG%20H1cVx%20M22IFBZC0ABoBMUICI3qgACIIpHIWTyN61RFFTjOIG6DjwbCUCDjQm0bGvbRg9ZfX7-MCA9y6UGrcEsqG3b4tPq05Go7QAOVa7RFOLkuEqzSlWKJThcnMq3HlNKe9LI%20J5zIgPz%20ANJIKZEO%20-MI3zWYFwlGVRWEom0AGVXPbHTLcfK3naHU7GKqzRxNdTGBMogBKOh0GC4DZDEAHI5dCCnJYXXnXHC3SgAHgEABVkCjICAyNQ7hg84RM1RkAAyWiyvHIN3IMbR6Lw5ACTvliCV6gNfgAPju1tWHGL0dndMYR3tUBT08okzjpQqyGL6oASphEsh9s8IgAFJgp7cQTAweaLc4Gq43HYREAENzQKIRLS%209pRFEHDrCUm7TLMYBMJA%20CULOB5HtEJ7II8jDPIwDIAIwykKCrZoaAC0GFBnEXQOm8ACC6DFqgABqACioyRrSaFMHqyAAEzYVKaLPkg%20HscRAawe6RAAKrFgA8gAYlJjFdnQURAA)

Comment: Thx for your help, I tried on my code, but it is still string. What is the minimum typescript version?

Comment: @fResult should be higher than 3.3

Comment: I am using ts 4.1.5, and updated at the post

Comment: @fResult you need to pass the whole array to the function and not a reference. Or use `as const` when you declare the array.